# Does counting extensions of standard Young tableaux determine its shape?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let us say that a standard Young tableau (SYT) of size $n + k$ extends an SYT of size $n$ if it results from adding $n+1, \ldots, n+k$ to the second SYT.  Define $f(\mu, k)$ to be the number of distinct SYTs that are extensions of size $n+k$ of some given SYT of shape $\mu$, that is, the number of distinct SYTs you can generate by adding $k$ numbers to a fixed SYT of shape $\mu$.  (Clearly, $f$ does not depend on the particular SYT chosen that is of shape $\mu$.)  $f(\mu, \cdot)$ is the rank census function of the tree of SYTs that extend $\mu$, which is a subtree of the tree of SYTs under extension.

I've written a program to compute $f$ for shapes up to size 10, and it appears that $f(\mu, \cdot)$ determines $\mu$ up to transposition of shapes.  Given that this result is simple and somewhat surprising, I would expect it to be known, but I haven't been able to find a reference for it, or any discussion of similar questions.  Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: Equivalently, $f(\mu,k)$ is the number of *skew* standard Young tableaux of skew shape $\lambda/\mu$, where $\lambda$ can be any shape of size $n+k$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your questoin, but a formula for $f(\mu,k)$ appears in Problem 107 at https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7supp.pdf, solution at https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7suppsol.pdf.